# row-fluid inside row-fluid with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am beginner of Bootstrap framework and i got the problem when i layout my design. I want to divide 4 column inside of a row-fluid so i write the code as below:

But it is not appear to what i expected, the text in first Lorem ipsum encroached to the second one and not fixed to 4 column

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span2"></div>
<div class="span8">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="span3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="span3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="span3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span2"></div>
```

Please anyone can help me,thanks in advance

Comment: the markup is correct, see this demo I made with your code http://jsfiddle.net/Jhtjz/3/embedded/result/

Comment: thanks i checked it again and it look still something off. i guess some other CSS is overlaped but thanks for your quick reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the html in `div.container-fluid` and closing the `div` tag for the row:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">First</div>
        <div class="span8">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                <div class="span3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                <div class="span3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                <div class="span3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="span2">Last</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's look more nice and fine with me. Thanks